# Resource not found in wpf project

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

so:

[image]

i write

```
StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("ProjectName;component/45.ani", UriKind.Relative));
```

but file not found :) why? project is bild

Comment: You have `ProjectName` in your string.  What's your project's actual name?

Comment: ... pardon?  Your comment makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

Can you check the build action on the file (on the properties panel) ? Is it set to "Resource" ?

Did you miss "Resources" ? (Maybe with UriKind.Absolute)

```
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ProjectName;component/Resources/45.ani", UriKind.Absolute)
```